# Insert variable | Data base | AT commands | SIM900

Tags: post, arduino, at-command, sim900

I trying to send data temperature from Arduino to data base... I've finished the connection, but I need replace a part of String, that is the static URL:

```
SIM900.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://mail.interseccion.com.mx:8901/dbTemperatura?Id_temp=0&Id_Device=1&Valor=-127.7&Temperatura_Action=Insert\"");
```

and this is my variable:

```
float = tmp;
tmp = sensor.getTempCByIndex(0);
```

And the URL I need replace the "-127.7" for the variable... but remember, the URL it's a String. I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: I've try to use the dtostrf() funtion, but I don't know how to use... I had though introduce url with the parameter into another String, but not.. that wasn't works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Arduino very much, but maybe this could help:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/FloatToString

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...

This is my URL
SIM900.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://mail.interseccion.com.mx:8901/dbTemperatura?Id_temp=0&Id_Device=1&Valor=-127.7&Temperatura_Action=Insert\"");

and the parameter to replace is the "-127.7"

I divided the URL on two parts into Strings...

```
String stringvar = String(tmp);
String stringurl1 = String("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://mail.interseccion.com.mx:8901/dbTemperatura?Id_temp=0&Id_Device=1&Valor=);
String stringurl2 = String("&Temperatura_Action=Insert\"");
String urlfinal = String(String(url1) + String(strinvar) + String(stringurl2));
```

For anyone has the same kind url...